# ¿Cómo contar números iguales consecutivos en Python?

Tags: python, string

Tengo que escribir un ejercicio, de un validador de números de tarjetas de crédito, en el que en una de las instancias se debe verificar si hay 3 numeros iguales consecutivos y retornar `false` en ese caso. El codigo hasta ahora va así:

```
num = input("Ingrese el numero de la tarjeta: ")

def validador():
    if tiene19() == True and empiezacon456() == True and gruposde4() == True and consecutivos() == True:
        return True

def tiene19():
    if len(num) == 19:
        return True

def empiezacon456():
    if num.startswith ("4" or "5" or "6"):
        return True
    
def gruposde4(*args):
    numsep = num.replace("-", " ")
    numsplit = numsep.split()
    if len(numsplit) == 4:
        return True

def consecutivos(*args):
    for digit in num:
```

y ahi me quedé. No importan las demás validaciones si estan bien o no, lo iré corrigiendo poco a poco, pero no encuentro un (o unos) métodos de cadena que me permitan verificar si hay 3 numeros consecutivos iguales.

Comment: Hola! Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Revisa de nuevo el [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: @Alfabravo listo! ya lo edite y puse el codigo que tengo hasta el momento. Gracias por tus consejos y perdon si pregunte mal, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: No existe un método de cadena que haga lo que buscas. Puedes recurrir a las [regex](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html) (que son una forma avanzada de analizar cadenas) o hacer tu propia función que haga eso. El método [isdecimal](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) de las cadenas puede serte de ayuda

Comment: @DanteS. gracias dante, si estuve leyendo la documentacion de python y no encontre ningun metodo de cadena que por si haga ese analisis, no tengo conocimiento de regex, pero si me animaria a escribir una funcion propia, solo que no se me ocurre como, podrian ayudarme o darme alguna orientacion de como hacerlo?

Comment: el validar los 3 numeros consecutivos quieres que toda la cadena sea de números consecutivos o basta con que una parte sea de números consecutivos?

Comment: @Christian hola christian, gracias por responder, la cadena ingresada debe ser de 19 caracteres (4 grupos de 4 digitos separados por un "-", ej (xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx), a traves de metodos de cadena como .replace, .split, y .join, debo hacer que la cadena quede solo con 16 digitos sin guiones de separadores (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) y recin ahi analizar si existen 3 caracteres consecutivos iguales

Comment: eso lo entiendo, pero si pot ejemplo tienes `1133-1234-5678-0213` debería de dar `True` o `False`??

Comment: @Christian a traves del metodo .replace("-", ""), logro que la cadena quede como "1133123456780213" y deberia dar True ya que no hay 3 numeros iguales consecutivos

Comment: y para `1111314477779012` ?

Comment: @Christian deberia retornar False ya que hay 1111 y 7777

Comment: @Christian He modificado mi pregunta para agradecerles, mostrarles el código completo y hacerles una última consulta, muchas gracias!

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta. Al modificar la pregunta los comentarios y respuestas terminan fuera de lugar y no se entienden. Lo mejor es [formular otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tu código se puede simplificar mucho empezando por la primera condición:

```py
if tiene19() == True and empiezacon456() == True and gruposde4() == True and consecutivos() == True:
```

Recordemos que al no haber un signo de comparación python por defecto evaluará si la condición es verdadera, por lo que podemos escribir:

```py
if tiene19() and empiezacon456() and gruposde4() and consecutivos():
```

También si hacemos una comparación `True==algo` nos retornará el resultado booleano de la comparación, usando este concepto podemos acortar más las siguientes 2 funciones.

```py
def tiene19():
    return len(num) == 19

def empiezacon456():
    return num[0] in "456"
```

Ahora sí pasando a tu problema real, lo que buscas no es nada complicado ni del otro mundo, es simplemente recorrer una cadena y verificar sus siguientes 3 posiciones. Para este caso he usado un ciclo `while` para recorrer la cadena y luego simplemente verificar las 3 posiciones siguientes, eso es todo.

```py
def consecutivos(*args):
    i=0
    while i+3<len(num):
        n = num[i]
        if f"{n*3}" == f"{num[i+1]}{num[i+2]}{num[i+3]}":
            return False
        i+=1
    return True
```

En la primera parte de la validación `f"{n*3}"` solamente usamos una propiedad de los strings, que cuando se les trata de operar con una multiplicación el string se repite n veces, por lo que al hacer `n*3` estamos repitiendo el string 3 veces, que por cierto podría quedar en solo `n*3` (sin necesidad de ponerlo en un f-string). La segunda parte solo accedemos las siguientes 3 posiciones y con ayuda de los f-strings juntamos cada uno de los resultados, es como hacer `str(num[i+1])+str(num[i+2])+str(num[i+3])`. Pero como `num` es una cadena fácilmente podemos concatenarla sin necesidad de f-strings, quedando así `num[i+1]+num[i+2]+num[i+3]`. Pero... aún podemos hacerlo mejor, podemos usar *slicing* cuya sintaxis es `cadena[inicio:fin:paso]`, lo que nos permite hacer `num[i: i+3]` lo que se traduce a que de la variable `num` solamente agarre lo que esta en la posición `i` hasta la posición `i+3`. Con todo esto el código quedaría así:

```py
def consecutivos(*args):
    i=0
    while i+3<len(num):
        n = num[i]
        if n*3 == num[i:i+3]:
            return False
        i+=1
    return True
```

Por cierto, yo recomendaría que todas las funciones reciban `num` como argumento, así te evitas de algunos problemas y el código se vuelve más fácil de leer y debugear.

Comment: muchas gracias! si tienes razon ya acorte las primeras funciones (supongo que esperaba dejar ese paso al ultimo cuando vea que las funciones funcionaban correctamente). Con respecto al problema de consecutivos, no estoy muy familiarizado con los f-strings aun, estoy averiguando sobre ello ahora (adelantandome un poco al curso) pero aun asi no logro comprender bien, habia hecho algo parecido con : 
if num[i] == num[i+1] == num[i+2]
pero me salta el error de "strings indices must be integers"

Comment: esa validación está mal, la variable `i` contiene la letra y no puedes hacer `numSinSep[i]`,deberías recorrer los índices o posiciones, no las letras. Además la comparación también está mal

Comment: Si lo se, solo te muestro como lo habia intentado hacer yo... la tuya funciona a la perfeccion solo que no la entiendo muy bien porque no estoy acostumbrado aun a usar f-strings, pero estoy en eso, voy a quedarme estudiandolas a ver si asi puedo comprender tu codigo, o existe alguna forma de hacerlo sin f-strings?

Comment: Mientras escribía la respuesta lo cambié a f-strings ya que lo había hecho con listas, la validación era así  `if [n]*3 == [num[i+1], num[i+2], num[i+3]]`. También puedes hacerlo con strings simples pero creo que el código crecería mucho.

Comment: O quizas puedas comentar el tuyo paso por paso asi comprendo bien cada linea de codigo? si no puedes o te parece demasiado no te preocupes lo entiendo, tampoco quisiera molestarte, aprecio muchisimo tu ayuda de todas formas!

Comment: listo agregué una explicación, además me di cuenta que compliqué las cosas, lo siento no he programado en unos meses.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias hermano! que tengas un excelente dia!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacer uso de expresiones regulares. Lo único que necesitas es una cadena en la que captures un caracter y compruebes que se repite dos veces más, es decir:

`(\d)\1{2}`

Esta regex busca un dígito `\d` lo guarda en una referencia al poner los paréntesis y busca ese mismo dígito a continuación (la referencia `\1`) repetido exactamente 2 veces `{2}`

Si quieres quitar los casos en los que haya más de 3 repeticiones puedes hacerlo con

`(\d)\1{3}`

Con todo esto te puedes construir una función que devuelva True cuando se encuentre la primera regex pero no la segunda:

```
import re

def check(num):
    return True if re.search(r'(\d)\1{2}', num.replace('-', '')) and not re.search(r'(\d)\1{3}', num.replace('-', '')) \
        else False
```

Comment: para un principiante es mejor priorizar la legibilidad antes que la simplificación. Tu respuesta no está mal, pero puedes darle un vistazo a la respuesta de @aeportugal.

Comment: Ok, echaré un vistazo a una respuesta que no da una explicación y que además no cumple con lo que pide el OP porque devuelve True si hay 4 repeticiones... :/

Comment: Aaa... bueno no la probé xd. Puedes dejarle un comentario sobre como mejorar la respuesta. Por cierto no critico tu respuesta, solo hablaba sobre la legibilidad :D

Comment: Tranqui, tranqui, estaba en plan sarcasmo xD. Publiqué mi respuesta sin ver que ya había enviado la suya

Comment: @CésarGonzález He modificado mi pregunta para agradecerles, mostrarles el código completo y hacerles una última consulta, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Una alternativa simple, sin expresiones regulares ni nada complicado:

```
def tres(numero):
    i = 2
    while i < len(numero):
        if numero[i] == numero[i - 1] and numero[i] == numero[i - 2]:
            return True
        i += 1

    return False
```

Simplemente recorre el numero comparando cada digito con los dos anteriores. Si son iguales, retorna de inmediato con `True`

**Demo**

```
tests= [
    "11",
    "11211",
    "111",
    "1112",
    "2111",
    "22333"
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, tres(test))
```

produce:

```
11 False
11211 False
111 True
1112 True
2111 True
22333 True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias Moe! eso era lo que buscaba, la alternativa mas simple y para principiantes que pudiera haber, lo que no entiendo es porque se define primero la variable i y se le va sumando 1 para salir del bucle while, no es mas facil hacerlo con un for?

Comment: @FacundoZavaleta. Cierto. No se que estaba pensado. Edite la pregunta para usar `for`.

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que esta solución asume que todos los caracteres de la cadena son numeros. Si hay una combinación de tres caracteres iguales (letras, numeros, simbolos, etc) esto devolverá True.

Comment: @DanteS.  Las tarjetas de crédito son numéricas. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Por eso dije "tener en cuenta". No que no sirva. Quizá alguien en el futuro quiera usar esa tecnica para obtener combinaciones de 3 numeros en una cadena que no sea todo numero.

Comment: @CandidMoe He modificado mi pregunta para agradecerles, mostrarles el código completo y hacerles una última consulta, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Una opción regex:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> print(re.search(r'(([0-9])\2{2,})', "8344 3535 2288"))
None
>>> print(re.search(r'(([0-9])\2{2,})', "8344 3555 2288"))
<re.Match object; span=(6, 9), match='555'>
```

[!] Creo que con un poco de investigación podrías poner toda la [validación de la tarjeta en un regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9315647/1545868). Sin embargo, más abajo otra persona menciona que [no se debería usar un regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019607/1545868) para validar toda la tarjeta. Pero si se puede usar para ir validando por partes, tal como tu pregunta.

Comment: uff muchas gracias! las voy a ir probando a todas pero las regex son bastante avanzadas para mi

Comment: @FacundoZavaleta Hice una aclaración en el último comentario, tocará investigar sobre el tema, pero puedes validar toda la tarjeta con distintos regex personalizados para cada condición y no saldría un código tan largo.

Comment: Pero esto devolvería True en caso de 4 repeticiones. No habría que excluir esos casos?

Comment: Si, devuelve un objeto si hay 3 o más coincidencias consecutivas. Si es 3 exclusivo, habría que modificar el regex.

Comment: @aeportugal He modificado mi pregunta para agradecerles, mostrarles el código completo y hacerles una última consulta, muchas gracias!